# Injecting ordered Beans into a Collection does not honour the defined order

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a number of beans all implementing the same type that are tagged with `@Order(x)` where `x` is the priority of the bean.

The beans are used by passing a collection of them into another bean as a parameter, however we use SonarQube to statically analyse our code, which suggests you should use a base class unless you are using specific features of the child class.

```
@Bean
public SomeProcessor someProcessor(Collection<MyBean> beans) {
  return new SomeProcessor(beans);
}
```

If I `@Inject` or pass these as a `List<>` they retain the order defined by the `@Order` annotations.

If I `@Inject` or pass these as a `Collection<>` they retain the order in which they were created, ignoring the `@Order` annotations.

Is this expected behaviour of Spring injection (using Spring Boot 2.4.4)?  Or is this something I should raise as a bug?

The following code demonstrates the problem (although in the production code we don't create Strings as Beans, as that would be... unusual):

```
@Inject
private List<String> stringList;

@Inject
private Collection<String> stringCollection;

@Bean
@Order(1)
public String stringBean1() {
  return "BEAN 1";
}

@Bean
@Order(3)
public String stringBean3() {
  return "BEAN 3";
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public String stringBean2() {
  return "BEAN 2";
}

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
  log.error("{}", stringCollection);
  log.error("{}", stringList);
}
```

The `List` is stored in order 1, 2, 3.
The `Collection` is stored in order 1, 3, 2, "ignoring" the `@Order` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring collection based ordering was finally implemented in version 4.0. The improvement is documented in this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10245).

The problem you indicated is described in a certain way in this other [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18761).

But as described there, and as also pointed out by @jwillebrands in his/her answer, a `Collection` may or may not be ordered, and Spring will only guarantee the order in [lists and arrays](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> Your target beans can implement the `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface or use the `@Order` or standard `@Priority` annotation if you want items in the array or list to be sorted in a specific order. Otherwise, their order follows the registration order of the corresponding target bean definitions in the container.

Comment: Darn, beat me to it :).

Comment: I tried to find a bug report that was similar to what I was seeing, but didn't spot the one you've linked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the behaviour is documented, but it is acceptable and understandable. `Collection` makes no statement about the underlying implementation, it could be ordered or unordered.

The docs say this

> A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not. Some are ordered and others unordered.

A `List` on the other hand is

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence).

You are, in fact, using a feature of the `List` class: its order. Changing to `Collection` here is incorrect in my opinion, as you require the collection to be ordered.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that `Collection` doesn't imply ordering - I guess I was expecting Spring to honor the ordering in the underlying choice of `Collection` implementation.
And you're also correct that by virtue of requiring the ordering, we _are_ using a feature of `List`, it's just not explicit in how we're using it.

As this issue was one raised by Sonar it's a valid use of a suppression in that case.